# How to sort dictionary on first element of the key (tuple)

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary where each key is a tuple of values, I want to use the `sorted()` method to sort the dictionary on the very first element of my tuple.  My code looks like this:

```
def mapData(header_list, dict_obj):
    master_dict = {}
    client_section_list = []
    for element in header_list:
        for row in dict_obj:
            if (row['PEOPLE_ID'], row['DON_DATE']) == element:
                client_section_list.append(row)
        element = list(element)
        element_list = [client_section_list[0]['DEDUCT_AMT'],
                    client_section_list[0]['ND_AMT'],
                    client_section_list[0]['DEDUCT_YTD'],
                    client_section_list[0]['NONDEDUCT_YTD']
                    ]
        try:
            element_list.append((float(client_section_list[0]['DEDUCT_YTD']) +
                                 float(client_section_list[0]['NONDEDUCT_YTD'])
                                 ))
        except ValueError:
            pass

    element.extend(element_list)
    element = tuple(element)
    master_dict[element] = client_section_list
    client_section_list = []
return sorted(master_dict, key=lambda key: key[master_dict[(1)]]
```

The last line is where I'm trying to find a way to sort it.  My tuple looks like this:

```
(312178078,6/22/15,25,0,25,0,25.0)
```

Comment: What is wrong with the code you have?

Comment: If the keys are tuples, than the dict will be sorted by the first element of those tuples by default. But if you _need_ to provide a key function, try `lambda key: key[0]`. Finally, note that `sorted(some_dict)` will return _only the keys_ in sorted order, not the entire dict, i.e. you lose the values!

Comment: You'll want to use `dict.items()` in the `sorted` function if your goal is to keep the entire dictionary structure. `return sorted(master_dict.items(), key=lambda key: key[0][0])` should do what you want.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you are trying to do, particularly what that function is supposed to return. I assume that you want to return the dictionary sorted by the first element in the key-tuples.

For this, there are two things to note:

1. Tuples are *by default* sorted by their first element (and if those are the same, then by the second, and so on), so no special key function is required
2. Regular dictionaries are unordered, i.e. they can not be permanently sorted in any order; you can only sort their items as a list, or use that list to create an [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) instead

Some minimal example:

```
>>> d = {(2,4): 1, (1,3): 2, (1,2): 3, (3,1): 4}
>>> sorted(d)
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 4), (3, 1)]
>>> sorted(d.items())
[((1, 2), 3), ((1, 3), 2), ((2, 4), 1), ((3, 1), 4)]
>>> collections.OrderedDict(sorted(d.items()))
OrderedDict([((1, 2), 3), ((1, 3), 2), ((2, 4), 1), ((3, 1), 4)])
```

In your case, you probably want this:

```
return collections.OrderedDict(sorted(master_dict.items()))
```

Answer (score 2):

As @tobias_k has mentioned, `sorted` sorts tuples by its elements with decreasing priority, e.g. if you take a tuple `(a, b, c)` the highest sorting priority goes to `a`, then goes `b` etc (by default `sorted` uses object's comparison methods and this is how `tuple` comparison works). So `sorted(master_dict)` is all you need if you want a list of sorted keys, yet I believe you really want to leave the values

```
sorted(master_dict.items(), key=lambda key: key[0])
```

`dict.items` returns tuples of form `(key, value)` so here you need to specify the sorting `key`.

Comment: Only partially correct. If you sort `dict.items()`, it will _again_ sort by the first element in the tuple by default, i.e. without providing a key function, dict-entries such as `((k1, k2, ...), (v1, v2, ...))` will be sorted by k1, then by k2, ..., then by v1, v2, .... etc.

Comment: @tobias_k that's why I do provide the `key` function in the `dict.items` part

Comment: But it does not have any effect. If `key` is a tuple, than `lambda key: key[0]` is the same as the default sorting order, except that there is no tie-breaking in case the first element in the same (but this can never be the case anyway, as keys are unique).

Comment: @tobias_k oh, now I see what you mean. In fact it does have a small effect of micro-optimization.